# filter by date with flask and mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, date, flask, filtering

I use flask_track_usage for tracking logs on my flask app.

I want to create a route which return logs filtered by date from my database mongodb.

for example :
api/tracking?to=02102020&from=03102020
return : yesterday's and today's logs

my route :

```py
@app.route('/api/tracking', methods=["GET"])
def tracking():
    start = datetime.strptime(request.args.get('from'),'%d%m%Y')
    end = datetime.strptime(request.args.get('to'),'%d%m%Y')
    tracking_filter(start,end)
    return "tracking"
```

my function :

```py
    def tracking_filter(self,start,end):
        for item in self.db["usageTracking"].find({"date": { "$gte": start,"$lt": end}}):
            print(item)
```

it doesn't return anything, can you help me with my function please?